# How to get data of user control when click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a new application like manager for cafe and I create an User Control for my application. My User Control's name is TableButton. It include Picture Box and Label and have three properties( ID, Name, Status).

When I add it in my form (with loop) and click it, it send to event data I do not want ( object sender is Picture Box or label depending on whether I click on a Picture Box or label. and I can't get data(ID, Name, Status). 
I want when I click anywhere in my TableButton then object sender is TableButton and I can get data from it.

So what's the solution for that?
My English is not good so maybe my article is wrong and difficult to understand. I hope you will skip this inconvenience. Thank you so much.

Comment: Make all controls you want to access `internal` (oe `public`) !  By default they all are `private` so you can't access them from outside. Not sure what you mean by those properties, though..

Comment: You should be able to access those properties my navigating to the senders parent container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want when I click anywhere in my tablebutton then object sender is
>   tablebutton and i can get data from it.

If you subscribe a handler to child control's `Click` event and fire user control's `Click` in the handler you will get the affect you want. You can do it:

```
public partial class TableButton : UserControl
{
    class TableButtonControlCollection : ControlCollection
    {
        TableButton owner;

        public TableButtonControlCollection(TableButton owner) : base(owner)
        {
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        public override void Add(Control value)
        {
            base.Add(value);
            value.Click += Value_Click;
        }

        private void Value_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            owner.OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    protected override ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
    {
        return new TableButtonControlCollection(this);
    }
}
```

Add this snippet into you `TableButton` class